# Pytorch mixed precision learning, torch.cuda.amp running slower than normal

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, torch, automatic-mixed-precision

I am trying to infer results out of a normal `resnet18` model present in `torchvision.models` attribute. The model is simply trained without any mixed precision learning, purely on **FP32**.
However, **I want to get faster results while inferencing**, so I enabled `torch.cuda.amp.autocast()` function only while running a test inference case.

The code for the same is given below -

```
model = torchvision.models.resnet18()
model = model.to(device) # Pushing to GPU

# Train the model normally
```

Without `amp` -

```
tensor = torch.rand(1,3,32,32).to(device) # Random tensor for testing
with torch.no_grad():
  model.eval()
  start = torch.cuda.Event(enable_timing=True)
  end = torch.cuda.Event(enable_timing=True)
  model(tensor) # warmup
  model(tensor) # warmpup
  start.record()
  for i in range(20): # total time over 20 iterations 
    model(tensor)
  end.record()
  torch.cuda.synchronize()
    
  print('execution time in milliseconds: {}'. format(start.elapsed_time(end)/20))

  execution time in milliseconds: 5.264944076538086
```

With `amp` -

```
tensor = torch.rand(1,3,32,32).to(device)
with torch.no_grad():
  model.eval()
  start = torch.cuda.Event(enable_timing=True)
  end = torch.cuda.Event(enable_timing=True)
  model(tensor)
  model(tensor)

  start.record()
  with torch.cuda.amp.autocast(): # autocast initialized
    for i in range(20):
      model(tensor)
  end.record()
  torch.cuda.synchronize()
  
  print('execution time in milliseconds: {}'. format(start.elapsed_time(end)/20))

  execution time in milliseconds: 10.619884490966797
```

Clearly, the `autocast()` enabled code is taking double the time. Even, with larger models like `resnet50`, the timing variation is approximately the same.

Can someone help me out regarding this ? I am running this example on **Google Colab** and below are the specifications of the GPU

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 465.27       Driver Version: 460.32.03    CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla P100-PCIE...  Off  | 00000000:00:04.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   43C    P0    28W / 250W |      0MiB / 16280MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
torch.version.cuda == 10.1
torch.__version__  == 1.8.1+cu101
```

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely because of the GPU you're using - P100, which has 3584 CUDA cores but 0 tensor cores -- the latter of which typically play the main role in mixed precision speedup. You may want to take a quick look at the "Hardware Comparison" section on this [article](https://www.xcelerit.com/computing-benchmarks/insights/benchmarks-deep-learning-nvidia-p100-vs-v100-gpu/).

If you're stuck to using Colab, the only way I can foresee a possible speedup is if you get assigned a T4, which has tensor cores.

Furthermore, it seems like you're using only a single image / a batch size of 1. If you get a T4, try re-running your benchmarks also using a larger batch size, like maybe 32-64-128-256 etc. You should be able to notice much more visible improvements when you parallelize over batches.